tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. --Answer and impacts of doing in one approach
If you face this issue, it is due to npm added new feature of signed powershell scripts to execute.
execute below command in powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
you can use this command for current user, you can change scope of users.
Impacts of setting Execution policy to remote singed can be:

you can not execute unsigned scripts in powershell
You may have to sign your scripts before executing.


In this case a preexisting post covers this topic already; generally speaking, to keep in mind for the future: it's great that you want to share a solution, but it's best to stick to the Q&A format: That is, limit the question to describing the problem / symptom, and then post an answer with the solution to your own question.
